# How did this violate "Nice?"

Tags: discussion

My answer was deleted on [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/how-to-get-out-of-a-tag-back-scenario/13807?noredirect=1#comment19873_13807) with a comment that I needed to follow the "Nice" policy.  I don't get how this wasn't nice; I was specifically addressing the interchange of childish "making up rules" invocations by the participants in the dispute that prompted the original question.  How is calling childish action childish a failure of "being nice?"

Answer (score 16):

You only read half of the closing comment. The user asked how to do this <thing> in work, but your answer was essentially to get another job. Here is the comment I left in that regard:

> These types of "just don't have the problem" solutions don't answer the question asked…

This is a problem on Lifehacks where folks ask (for example) how to get a spaghetti stain out of their shirt, and folks suggest not spilling food on themselves in the first place.

And the answer itself was written in a way to pander to the crowd through name-calling and snark. Here is the answer I removed:

> I'd suggest looking for a different job that employs adults, rather than grade school children.

That is not the tone we wish to set in the context of an answer on the site. I thought I should mention our broad "Be Nice" policy to clarify the issue.

Comment: If not deleted and the question on hold, I might edit the answer.  My experience (since 1979) has been that finding a different job is the only way out of this kind of "working with children" problem.